# Play Framework: How to declare member in CRUD model which should not display in UI

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am building a administrative page using a Play framework CRUD model. i.e I have a model called 'User' which have many variables. When I run this application all the member variables are displayed in UI. I dont want to display createdDate, creadedBy, updatedDate, updatedBy in UI.. Is there any annotation to avoid that?

```
package models;

import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

import play.db.jpa.*;
import play.data.validation.*;

@Entity
public class User extends Model {

    @Email
    @Required
    public String email;

    @Required
    public String password;

    public String fullname;
    public boolean isAdmin;

    public Date createdDate;
    public Date modifiedDate;
    public String createdBy;
    public String modifiedBy;
}
```

Comment: then why are you displaying those fields?

Comment: @deogratias, I guess my question might not be clear to you.. When you enable the CRUD module for playframework, you just need to write Model and Controller. UI(html pages) will be generated autmatically.. Hence HTML page will be generated based on member variables.. 
Ref:https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.4/guide7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding the annotation

```
@CRUD.Exclude
```

You won't have the field appear.
Also, if you use

```
@CRUD.Hidden
```

The field will appear in a hidden html input in the CRUD forms.

I can't point you towards any documentation, I just found these in CRUD.java